# Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing the HTTP request and getting response in my `func`. It return the value of response. I am doing it this way:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        stringResponse = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        if stringResponse == "0" {
            return false
        } else if stringResponse == "1" {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

But on all `return`s I have error `Unexpected non-void return value in void function` How to fix this?

Comment: You should return out side the closure. Else the calling function should have a closure.

Comment: I need to return value only when I have it

Comment: In that case you need to have a closure.

Comment: Please write it as a question with code

Comment: let me guess: that code is written inside another method which has Bool as return type? That will not work because it is an asynchronous request.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do this if you want the value after you get response.

```
func getResponse(completionHandler : ((isResponse : Bool) -> Void)) {

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        stringResponse = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        if stringResponse == "0" {
           completionHandler(isResponse : false)
        } else if stringResponse == "1" {
           completionHandler(isResponse : true)
        } else {
           completionHandler(isResponse : false)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you call it as below from where ever you are calling.

```
classObject.getResponse {(isResponse) -> Void in 

//Do your stuff with isResponse variable.
}
```

Comment: worked for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of `sendAsynchronousRequest` is a completion handler with type `(NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void`. Note it doesn't have any return type, so don't return anything.

The completion handler is called by the connection framework, it doesn't need any return type.

It's pretty obscure what you are trying to achieve by that returns but you can't do it this way.