# Swift 1.2: Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Tags: json, xcode, swift, function

I have written a function which should return a certain value from a page. I have done this with JSON, so that I can get a certain value from my website. This is the function:

```
func getTimerData() {
    var currentUsername = PFUser.currentUser()!.username

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://dinges.informatica-dinges.nl/timerDataTransmitter.php?user=\(currentUsername!)&unique=85017438957")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        var parseError: NSError?
        if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: &parseError) as? [String: String] {

            let rideTime = json["timerValue"]
            return rideTime

        }
    }
}
```

However, it gives me the error: `Unexpected non-void return value in void function`. I have tried a lot but I can't seem to find a way to fix this problem. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: `func getTimerData() -> NSTimeInterval`, or whatever is the type of `rideTime`

Comment: You can't return anything because `dataTaskWithRequest` works asynchronously. Use a completion block or a notification.

Comment: @vadian Could you please tell me how to do this? I haven't really used completion blocks or notifications yet.

Comment: In the `Related` column there are some suggestions for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279359/unexpected-non-void-return-value-in-void-function?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Declare your function with return data type as you required
such as :

```
fun getTimerData() -> String {
    var currentUsername = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
    let url = NSURL(string: “http://dinges.informatica-dinges.nl/timerDataTransmitter.php?user=\(currentUsername!)&unique=85017438957”)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

    var parseError: NSError?
    if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: &parseError) as? [String: String] {
        let rideTime = json["timerValue"]
        return rideTime
    }
  }
}
```