# Execute a function before the orientation change

Tags: ios, swift

When the orientation changes, is it possible to execute a function and wait for it until it finish executing and then perform the rotation? Something like that:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

         doStuff()

        // block until doStuff is done
        weak var weakSelf = self
        coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in

            }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in  

        })
    }
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: @Tj3n, `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated since iOS8

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
func doStuff(check:(_ Check : Bool)->Void){

    check(true)
}
```

and inside `viewWillTransitionToSize` func :

```
doStuff { (myCheck) in
        if myCheck{

            // do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there an alternative for swift 2.3 ?

Comment: @ella23 Look this answer it uses the same logic function in swift 2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30279539/3108877